# Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) with 3 verices and 3 toplogical orderings

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to create a DAG with 3 vertices and 3 topological orderings. All I can think of to do is the following graph (or the same graph with both edges' directions reversed):

[image]

This yields 2 toplogical orderings:

- A B C
- A C B

I cannot think of an example where 3 different topological orderings is obtainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no *connected* graph on 3 vertices with 3 topological orderings of a particular labelling.

However, what about disconnected ones? If we have A->B.C then the orderings are

- A B C
- A C B
- C A B

where we are just shifting C along the list.